# Resource Leak error in Klockwork

Tags: c, sockets, memory-leaks, tcp, klocwork

[image]
Klocwork shows
RH.LEAK
Resouce acquired "newConn" may lost here. (line return newConn).

Why i got this warning ? Please help me out.

Comment: I don't see any problem with the pseudo code. Real code and exact error message are needed.

Comment: @user3386109 :
Error message : Resource acquired "newConn" may lose here.

Comment: @user3386109, i have attached snapshot.

Comment: That's a bug in the analyzer. The analyzer doesn't realize that the `accept` failed when it returns `SOCKET_ERROR`. If you `return newConn;` instead of `return SOCKET_ERROR;`, the warning should go away.

Comment: @user3386109: Thanks.

Comment: This vanished for me when I had a similar problem after cleaning and rebuilding the code.